# Rail Devise creat own sign_in and sign_out actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, devise, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I have the following problems with dives in rails.

**All requests and response are JSON**

After I sign in **/partners/sign_in** I get the following response:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
>   {"success":true}

And after i signed out **/partners/sign_out** I get thie following response:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
>   {"success":true}

Now my Question:
How can I create my own RegisterController and HOW it looks like, are there any examples? I have searched at github/devise but not find any examples.

I want to response something other, and if the authentication fails I want to response HTTP 404 ERROR

**routes.rb**

```
devise_for :partners, :controllers => { :sessions => "sessions" }
```

**session_controller.rb**

```
  class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  def create
    resource = warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => :failure)
    return sign_in_and_redirect(resource_name, resource)
  end

  def destroy
    redirect_path = after_sign_out_path_for(resource_name)
    signed_out = (Devise.sign_out_all_scopes ? sign_out : sign_out(resource_name))
    set_flash_message :notice, :signed_out if signed_out

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to redirect_path }
      format.json { render :json => {:success => true} }
    end
  end

  private

  def sign_in_and_redirect(resource_or_scope, resource=nil)
    scope = Devise::Mapping.find_scope!(resource_or_scope)
    resource ||= resource_or_scope
    sign_in(scope, resource) unless warden.user(scope) == resource
    return render :json => {:success => true}
  end

  def failure
    return render:json => {:success => false, :errors => ["Login failed."]}
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ActionController's render method takes hash with :status as the key. Here you can specify the HTTP error status code or the symbol for that status code:

```
render json: {success: false, errors: ["Login Failed"]}, status: 404  
# or the following is a preferred way
render json: {success: false, errors: ["Login Failed"]}, status: :not_found
```

Here the documentation for [render method](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render).
And here is an excellent documentation by Cody Fauser of [rails status code to symbol mapping](http://www.codyfauser.com/2008/7/4/rails-http-status-code-to-symbol-mapping)

One Observation:

It is not idiomatic in Ruby to use return statements at the end of a function because the last expression's return value is the return value of the function.